# MySQL: Can't find any matching row in the user table

Tags: mysql, sql-grant

When I want to give a user full permission to the database like this:

```
GRANT PROXY ON 'homestead'@'%' TO 'homestead'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Users:

```
 +-----------+
    | User      |
    +-----------+
    | homestead |
    | homestead |
    | root      |
    | mysql.sys |
    | root      |
    +-----------+
```

It returns:

```
Can't find any matching row in the user table
```

Comment: please check your environment using 'php artisan env' if it is local in homestead then you can run your migration.

Comment: That's just the point I can't!

Comment: may be it is possible your environment is production because homestead default has permissions.

Comment: Please see my edit for .env file

Comment: Shouldn't your query be: `GRANT PROXY ON homestead.* TO`?

Comment: @ash You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.* TO' at line 1

Comment: Ignore that - what you're doing is fine.  I'm trying to understand the error - when you run that `GRANT` query does it respond with that `Can't find...` error?

Comment: Yes this is the error: 
ERROR 1133 (42000): Can't find any matching row in the user table

Comment: So next question is does the `homestead` user exist on BOTH databases?

Comment: Yes it does exist in both.